# Find result in between date range in mysql not working properly

Tags: php, mysql

I've made a query below but it fetch only one row while there are two rows between this date range in database:

```
SELECT * FROM resorts_seasonallevelpricingnew INNER JOIN resorts_resort ON
resorts_seasonallevelpricingnew.resortId = resorts_resort.resortId INNER JOIN 
resorts_roomtype ON
resorts_seasonallevelpricingnew.roomTypeId =  resorts_roomtype.roomTypeId WHERE   
resorts_seasonallevelpricingnew.resortId = 601 AND 
resorts_seasonallevelpricingnew.roomTypeId = '8' AND 
( ('2016-03-01 00:00:00' BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE(`fromDate`,'%Y-%m-%d') 
AND STR_TO_DATE(`toDate`,'%Y-%m-%d')) OR ('2016-03-31 00:00:00' 
BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE(`fromDate`,'%Y-%m-%d') AND STR_TO_DATE(`toDate`,'%Y-%m-%d')) )
```

there are two rows in database with following dates and it should fetch both of them:
1- from: 15-03-2016 to: 23-03-2016
2- from: 24-03-2016 to: 31-03-2016

what i want is when user select from and to date from date picker and search it should display all record coming between from and to date. 
For example if user searched for date 1-03-2016 to 31-03-2015 and there is a row in database with from and to dates 25-03-2016 to 10-04-2016. it should get that row because it's to date comes in between searched date.

Comment: Are the right rows being returned when you remove the `WHERE` clause?

Comment: yes. it gives right rows when i remove date's AND

Comment: Have you tried the simpler `between '25-03-2016' and '10-04-2016'`

Comment: yes I've used between and it worked. I've posted my answer. Thanks for quick help.

Comment: I've noticed another problem in it. it only search if dates are in between given dates. but what if dates are from 21 to 31-03-2016 and I search for 23 to 24-03-2016, it should search this too.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for. I'm posting my answer if someone else might need this one.

```
SELECT * FROM resorts_seasonallevelpricingnew 
INNER JOIN resorts_resort ON resorts_seasonallevelpricingnew.resortId = resorts_resort.resortId 
INNER JOIN resorts_roomtype ON resorts_seasonallevelpricingnew.roomTypeId = 
resorts_roomtype.roomTypeId 
WHERE resorts_seasonallevelpricingnew.resortId = 
601 
AND resorts_seasonallevelpricingnew.roomTypeId = '8' 
AND ( 
(STR_TO_DATE(`fromDate`,'%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN '2016-03-01 00:00:00' AND 
'2016-03-31 00:00:00') 
OR (STR_TO_DATE(`toDate`,'%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN 
'2016-03-01 00:00:00' AND '2016-03-31 00:00:00'))
ORDER BY 
resorts_seasonallevelpricingnew.fromDate
```